# Corollary of Riemann Mapping Theorem

Tags: complex-analysis

I was trying to prove the uniqueness of the map in the Riemann mapping Theorem. I'm not sure if the proof I wrote is right.

Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{C}$ be a simply connected open subset such that $\Omega \neq \mathbb{C}$.

Then given $a \in \Omega$ there exists an unique conformal bijection   $ $ $ f: \Omega \rightarrow D(0,1)$ with $f(a)=0$ and $f'(a)>0$

$Proof:$

Suppose two conformal bijections $f,g$ with these properties. It's clear  that $f \circ g^{-1}$ is a bijection of the unit disk. It follows

$f \circ g^{-1}=e^{i\theta}f_{\alpha}$ we know that  $f \circ g^{-1}(0)=0$ so $\alpha =0$

so $f \circ g^{-1}=e^{i\theta}z$

$g(z)=e^{-i\theta}f(z)$ $\implies$ $g'(z)=e^{-i\theta}f'(z)>0$ and $\theta=0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The assertion that since $f'(z)$ and $g'(z)$ are positive, they must be constant functions ... that's wrong. In fact, the function values aren't necessarily even real.

I suggest that (as in many uniqueness proofs), you look at $f^{-1} \circ g$, which is (in a small enough neighborhood) equal to the identity, and then see where that gets you.

Your statement of the theorem seems to me to be wrong also. Consider $\Omega = D(0, 1)$, and $a = 0$. Let $f(z) = z$ and $g(z) = z/2$. Then $f'(a)$ and $g'(a)$ are both positive, and $f$ and $g$, being analytic, are both conformal maps, but they're not equal.

Comment: regarding the statement of the theorem i used the word map instead of bijection my fault.

So $f>0$ doesn't mean that it is a real valued function? Could you give an example please?

Anyway in your counterexample  $g$ in $\frac{1}{3}$ goes outside of the unit disk.

Comment: I found the right answer ill post it soon. Thanks for pointing my mistake!

Comment: I fixed the $g$ problem by making it $z/2$ instead of $2z$. It's true that it's not a  bijection...but when you wrote the problem, a bijection was not required. As for $f > 0$, that would indeed suggest it was a real-valued function...but $f(a) > 0$ only means that the value at $a$ is real, not that all other values are. There really aren't any real-valued conformal functions on $\mathbb C$. :(